# What is the )K-like symbol?

Tags: symbols

I was reading Class Field Theory by Emil Artin and John Tate, and there is a commutative diagram in it:

[image]

What is the symbol of the horizontal arrows? How can I type it?

Comment: This is the 8th letter in the Russian/Cyrillic Alphabet Ж.